# If a program installed as root is run by a non root user will it still have root priviledges?

Tags: linux, permissions, root

If a program installed as root is run by a non root user will it still have root privileges?

Thanks very much!

Comment: No in general. But read more about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

Comment: Everything in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` was installed by root. Do you observe that all of it runs as root? QED.

Comment: Take some time to carefully read about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sorry didnt read that through. Anyway I can tell whether a program uses setuid without the users knowledge?

Comment: Take *more* time to read about it. Read also [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the installation procedure, but in general no.